# Semi Transparent Overlay in Flutter app, installed in a physical android device in Debug Mode

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

In my flutter project (latest version), I use a physical android device for development. But in my phone, in the flutter debug app, **a semi transparent black overlay is always showing...** I tried to run a new project & there also was an overlay.. I don't know if it is the issue with my flutter sdk or my device.

#### My Code so far

```dart
//main.dart
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}
```

Other widgets

```dart
//home.main.dart
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        title: Text("SHKSC", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.indigoAccent[50])),
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.blue, opacity: 0.7),
      ),
      body: HomeBody(), /* Incoming from home.body */
    );
  }
}
```

The image of the running app on my physical device in **Scrcpy**..
[ImageLink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBP3c.jpg)

Comment: are you pushing any empty screens or dialogues? please show more body code

Comment: thanks @Yadu, but I fixed it. It was actually a problem with my phone. I'm using CynogenMod 13.1 in which the theme store's applied themes were forcefully changing the Background of the Scaffold. After using the default android theme, it works now

Comment: most welcome...